# Which operators should I implement in my class?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have created my own class like this:

```
template<class T>
class ball
{
    T size;
    T price;
};
```

Now I want to support comparing two balls only according to the first value `size` in this case should I implement all those operators for `ball` class??

```
==, !=, >=, <=, >, <
```

This doesn't sound efficient or correct.

Comment: I wouldn't overload any of them for size alone, as such operators would likely be confusing without proper contextual information (and maybe even with it). If you want to, say, sort by size, probably better to use something more explicit (e.g. a lambda or other comparator function).

Comment: Apart from what @scg says – *if* your compiler already supports, you might just implement the space ship operator `<=>` coming with C++20. Be aware that, though, at the time being it won't be portable code until the new standard is released.

Comment: Rememeber that `!=` can be implemented in terms of `==` and `>`, `<=` and `>=` can all be implemented in terms of `<` so its not so much work to implement all the operators.

Comment: Before C++20, implementing all the operators you need is correct - whether it is efficient depends on your measure of efficiency, but there is no choice but to implement all of the operators you reasonably expect are needed.   You might write a helper function to (you know) help you do that more efficiently.   Depending on properties of `T`, there are templated function objects in `<functional>` (`std::less`, `std::less_equal`, etc) that may be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which operators should I implement in my class?

In general, at minimum you should implement those operators which you use. And the ones that are required by concepts that you need the class to fulfill.

If you want the class to be equality comparable, then ideal design is to also let the class be comparable using `operator!=` and if you want the class to be comparable with ordered relations, then ideal design is to let the class be comparable with all operators.

> should I implement all those operators for ball class??

Pre-C++20: Yes, this is a good idea if you want the class to be comparable.

Since C++20: No, you should in most cases only implement `operator<=>`. Preferably as defaulted.

---

> I want to support comparing two balls only according to the first value size

I recommend to not define the comparison operators to behave this way. It will be highly confusing to the users of your class as they will likely expect the price to affect the equality of the object.

If you need this kind of comparison for a specific use case, then I recommend using a custom comparison object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to implement a method supporting all cases. An advantage would be that you could choose the test dynamically at runtime :

```
// in .hpp
typedef enum { Equal, LessOrEqual, GreaterOrEqual, NotEqual, GreaterThan, LessThan } Comparator;
bool compare(ball & a, ball & b, Comparator c = Equal);

// in .cpp
bool compare(ball & a, ball & b, Comparator c) {
    bool r;
    switch(c) {
        case GreaterOrEqual: case LessThan: r = a.size >= b.size; break;
        case LessOrEqual: case GreaterThan: r = a.size <= b.size; break;  
        default:                            r = a.size == b.size; break;
    }
    return c >= NotEqual ? !r : r;
}
```